# Constructor cannot be applied to given types, creating objects in Java, object oriented programming

Tags: java, oop, object, subclass, superclass

I am trying to write a program (`Driver`) that will create `Humans` and their `Pets` and specific types as seen below.

I have run into multiple errors: in the Driver program, the error is when I try to do `Humans b = new Humans();` and I get: 
`constructor Humans in class Humans cannot be applied to given types.`

Additionally, if I try to write out `Humans b = new Humans("Jane", Pet/Dog...)` I am unsure of how to specify the type of Pet for the person.

Any help and direction would be appreciated.

```
public class Humans {
    String name;
    Pets pet;
    int popcount;

    public Humans(String hname, Pets hpet) {
        name = hname;
        pet = hpet;
    }

    public int populationCount() {
        return popcount;
    }

    public void makePetMakeNoise() {
        int randnum = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
        pet.makeNoise(randnum);
    }

    public void feedPet() {
        pet.eat();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Pets {
    String name;
    String noise;
    boolean canMakeNoise;

    public Pets(String pname, String pnoise, boolean pcanmakenoise) {
        name = pname;
        noise = pnoise;
        pcanmakenoise = canMakeNoise;
    }

    public void makeNoise(int number) {
        if (canMakeNoise != false) {
            for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
                System.out.println(noise + name);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println(name + " *remains silent*");
        }
    }

    public void eat() {
        System.out.println(name + " is eating...");
    }

    class Dog extends Pets {
        public Dog(String pname, String pnoise, boolean pcanmakenoise) {
            super(pname, pnoise, pcanmakenoise);
        }

        public void eat() {
            System.out.println(name + " is eating...");
        }
    }

    class Cat extends Pets {
        public Cat(String pname, String pnoise, boolean pcanmakenoise) {
            super(pname, pnoise, pcanmakenoise);
        }

        public void eat() {
            super.eat();
            System.out.println("I'm still hungry, meow");
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Driver {
    public Driver() {
        Humans b = new Humans();
        b.name = "Jane";
        Pets bb = new Pets(Cat);
        b.pet = bb;
        bb.canMakeNoise = true;
        bb.name = "Bertha";
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add(b);

        ListIterator<String> itr = list.listIterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            String str = itr.next();
            str.makePetMakeNoise();
            str.feedPet();
        }
        System.out.println(Humans.populationCount());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please try to only provide a [clear and minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); your code is way too long here!

Comment: It would be good to think about what an object of each class represents. In your case, an object of `Humans` represents a single Human, so it's better to name your class `Human` (without the s). The same goes for `Pets`. It's only a good idea to use plural when an object of the class really represents more than one (like a list of Humans).

Answer (score 3):

The first issue you're seeing is that you're trying to pass no arguments to the Humans constructor but you didn't define a constructor that takes no arguments.  The easy fix for this specific error is to add a default constructor to Humans:

```
public Humans() {}
```

Probably more inline with what you're trying to do would be to call the constructor you have.  To do this you need to pass a name and pet to `Humans(String, Pets)`, as you seem to have figured out.

Creating a Pets object is straightforward, but you don't specify the type of pet like you're trying: each subclass of Pets is itself a class, so you would call `new Pets.Cat(...)` rather than trying to invoke something on Pets.

This gets us to:

```
Pets bb = new Pets.Cat("Bertha", "meow", true);
Humans b = new Humans("Jane", bb);
```

This will lead to more compile errors, but hopefully that helps with the construction questions you asked.

---

Comments about naming conventions/structure:

1. Object names are typically not plural: an instance of your `Humans` class represents a single human, not multiple humans (currently at least, not sure where you're going with `population`), so it would be more appropriately named `Human`.
2. Child classes don't need to be placed inside their parent.  `Dog` and `Cat` more typically would be placed outside the `Pets` class: the inheritance of `extends Pets` informs the user/compiler of the relationship with `Pets`, the location of the class definition doesn't need to.

Answer (score 1):

You can't constuct objects like this

```
Humans b = new Humans();
b.name = "Jane";
Pets bb = new Pets(Cat);
b.pet = bb; bb.canMakeNoise = true;
bb.name = "Bertha";
```

Because you make `Cat` and `Dog` [non-static nested classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) or inner (and because class members are  private by default) you need to constract them like this

```
Pets p = new Pets("AllPets", "SomeSound", true);
Humans b = new Humans("Jane", p.new Cat("Bertha", "meow", true));
```

And the full code

```
Pets p = new Pets("AllPets", "SomeSound", true);
Humans b = new Humans("Jane", p.new Cat("Bertha", "meow", true));
ArrayList<Humans> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(b);

ListIterator<Humans> itr = list.listIterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    Humans h = itr.next();
    h.makePetMakeNoise();
    h.feedPet();
    System.out.println(h.populationCount());
}
```

However, in this case `Pets` having constructor arguments makes no sense. So I guess you want `Cat` and `Dog` to be static. Like this

```
static class Cat extends Pets {
    ...
}
static class Cat extends Pets {
    ...
}
```

Or you could define them outside of the parent class (which makes even more sense).

Then you can create objects

```
Pets p = new Pets.Cat("Bertha", "mew", true);
Humans b = new Humans("Jane", p);
```

Also you can't add `Humans` objects to `String` list (see the above code).

Answer (score 0):

**have run into multiple errors: in the Driver program, the error is when I try to do Humans b = new Humans(); and I get:  constructor Humans in class Humans cannot be applied to given types.**

Because you have created a parameter-lize constructor so there is no parameter-less constructor.

> Note:- If we create constructor manually compiler didn't put the default constructor automatically.

So to solve this issue you need to create,

**Human b=new Human("John Doe",new Pet("Lassy","Meyyeww",true));**